# Determine Remote Desktop Protocol version programmatically?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, protocols

Remote Desktop Protocol version 6.1 changed the way RDP sessions are handled (making session 0, which previously meant "console session", into a non-interactive session).  I need to be able to figure out from within my program how to determine just what version of the RD protocol is being used on the current RDP session.  Nothing I can find in the Windows Terminal Services API, however, seems to give me the protocol version.

Comment: Why do you need to know this information?  The vast majority of programs should be written without any knowledge of whether the user is infront of the screen or remote desktop.

Answer (score 2):

the `WTSClientBuildNumber` attribute in the `WTS_INFO_CLASS` contains the client build number which appears to be the version of the client's RDP.

The `WTS_INFO_CLASS` enumeration type contains values that indicate the type of session information to retrieve in a call to the `WTSQuerySessionInformation` function.

[here is the msdn terminal services api article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383861(VS.85).aspx)