# Determine Remote Desktop Client supported protocol version

Tags: remote-desktop

How do I determine the Remote Desktop Protocol version supported by a particular client?

Note that I am NOT asking for the ActiveX control version but the underlying protocol version. As examples from two machines I checked using `Help`->`About` (or just `About` in the case of Windows XP):

- On Windows 8, I do NOT want `6.2.9200`, I want `8.0`.
- On Windows XP, I do NOT want `6.0.6001`, I want `6.1`.

And I am not asking for the protocol version in use in a given session (which is what [Determine Remote Desktop Protocol version programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930462/determine-remote-desktop-protocol-version-programatically) is referring to) because we're not in a session, we are validating a client's configuration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually contact Microsoft about this question and the (somewhat amazing) answer I got back is as follows:

> That string is hard-coded and not retrieved from the server or AX (in
>   fact mstsc.exe checks the build number of mstsax.dll before loading it
>   to make sure it is consistent with its own build number).

So I guess I will need to fall back on hard-coded OS version information - perhaps the mstsc.exe version. That's yucky but I don't see what choice I have.

Comment: Ultimately, I ended up just looking for what I actually really needed, namely the existence of an appropriate RDP client version entry in COM (attempt to instantiate the version I need, see if it works).